# regarding to dependecy and depepndecy injection

Tags: dependency-injection, dependencies, magento2

I want to know what is dependency and dependency injection is in Magento 2 as I want to know the very basic definition from real-world example because I have surf a lot but not getting the idea about this terms if you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is a principle for decoupling your application. Here the definition :

> Entities must depend on abstractions, not on concretions. It states that the high-level module must not depend on the low-level module, but they should depend on abstractions.

That mean you use the interface instead of the concrete class

For more details, see the SOLID principles

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual_articles/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design